# Test app on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I need to test my app on iOS 7.1 but ran out of options.

My setup:

- MacBook running El Capitan Xcode 7
- No physical devices running iOS 7

I cant run the iOS 7 simulator - the simulator says that the runtime cannot be found and I cannot download iOS 7 from "downloads.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My advice：
(Remind: my English is limited, my expression is not very good!)
1.We can use Xcode7 to compiler to generate debug app
2.Use the xcode - select switch commandline tool to Xcode6.4
3.Run xcode6.4 iOS7 simulator
4.Using xcrun simctl installed test app to xcode6.4 iOS7 simulator
5.Run to check the effect (can't debugging)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I dont have Xcode 6.4

Comment: You can download it from developer.apple.com. Click Xcode, then find "Additional Tools" and download Xcode 6.4.3 from there

Comment: I havent tested it, but it would probably work, but seems like hard work and one cannot even debug :(

Comment: That method can only see the running effect, can't debug!